# Multiple DbContext instances to the same database using single ambient TransactionScope without DTC

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, transactions, npgsql

Sounds like most of questions on the internet, but here is the thing - when multiple connections are made during single ambient `TransactionScope` it will be promoted to DTC. So the question is, how to avoid this and share single connection among all the instance? There is a connection pooling mechanism (at least in `Npgsql`) but I'm not sure it works as I expected it would be.

This is a repro: https://github.com/uhfath/TestTransactionDbContext

The project contains testing methods for `Npgsql` and `Sql Server`. They behave differently:

- On `Sql Server` I simply get `The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction`.
- On `Npgsql` the queries simply don't work.

What the project does is:

- starts an ambient `TransactionScope`:

```cs
private static TransactionScope CreateTransaction() =>
    new TransactionScope(
        TransactionScopeOption.Required,
        new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        },
        TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
```

- creates a test client:

```cs
private static async Task<Client> Create(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var client = new Client { Name = "client_1" };

    await using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateAsyncScope();
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AsyncDbContext>();
    dbContext.Clients.Add(client);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Client: {client.Id}");
    return client;
}
```

- starts 100 tasks to read this created client (using returned Id):

```cs
private static Random _randomer = new();
private static async Task Read(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DependentTransaction dependentTransaction, int clientId, int index)
{
    using (dependentTransaction)
    {
        //using (var transaction = CreateTransaction(dependentTransaction))
        {
            await using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateAsyncScope())
            {
                var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AsyncDbContext>();
                await Task.Delay(_randomer.Next(100, 250));
                var client = await dbContext.Clients.AsNoTracking().Where(cl => cl.Id == clientId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Read: {index} -> {client?.Id.ToString() ?? "!! NOT FOUND !!"}");
                //transaction.Complete();
            }
        }

        dependentTransaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

The main issue is that I need to read data in parallel and this is just a simple example of the main, bigger project where the goal is the same (it just uses plugins that are executed in parallel and each instantiates `DbContext` through DI).

As I mentioned, when using `Sql Server` I get an exception, but when using `Npgsql` the query sometimes returned correct result and sometimes `!! NOT FOUND !!`. The latter makes be believe that a transaction was somehow 'rolledback' by the time the query was run.

So how do we actually share a connection among all these `DbContext` instances so transaction wouldn't escalate to DTC?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure SQL Server natively can even do multiple sessions in same transaction without DTC. Why do you need transaction if you're reading anyway? See also https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/13

Comment: @siggemannen, reading here is just for simplicity. In an actual project there are different cases. One main is that all work is done through repositories which use `DbContext` through DI. And these repositories are instantiated also through DI from within plugins. So perhaps some sort of manual connection sharing would be suffice, I guess, but how to do that for EF Core? Perhaps in this case there wouldn't be multiple sessions but one single session, hence no need for DTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two threads can't use the same DbContext instance at the same time.

Two DbContext instances can't use the same Ado.Net connection object at the same time.

If two DbContext instances try to share a System.Transactions.Transaction *at the same time* a distributed transaction is required.  If they share the transaction one-at-a-time a distributed transaction is not needed.

So no, you cannot read data in parallel with multiple sessions in the same transaction without a distributed transaction*.

*SQL Server does have an ancient feature called "bound connections" that lets multiple sessions share a single transaction, but I would stay away from that.  Instead if sessions need to share data during a transaction, use a global temp table.

Comment: Short and clear. Thanks. No parallel reading then.

Comment: You can read in parallel all you want, but the parallel readers won't be viewing a transactionally consistent view of the data.  One reader may see committed transactions that another does not.

Comment: Yeah. I meant "no parallel reading" just in this case, using single ambient transaction. Other cases are working just fine.